# how to disable notification sound programmatically from another app

Tags: android

I was wondering if it was possible to mute notification sounds programmatically?
what I wanted to achieve with this is that a user can select which apps he wants to mute from a single app instead of entering into the settings menu

Comment: Generally, apps cannot affect the behavior of other apps this way.

Comment: not even mute their sound? that's a shame

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible by design. 
Android idea for app is to run app in sandbox and do not allow it affect any other applications.